# Linux server management tool

Tags: linux, sysadmin

I recently deployed 13 servers (Red Hat 7.2). I would like to know what will be an ideal server management tool that will allow me to patch, and automate servers within a small environment such as mine.

If possible not very difficult to configure and maintain.

Comment: Satelite, Ansible. There is a lot of them out there.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/269617/linux-equivalent-to-powershells-one-to-many-remoting/269626#269626 ... and Spacewalk, the open source equivalent of RH Satellite

Comment: Thanks but I just found out Spacewalk only supports Fedora, CentOS, SLE and Debian. No Support for Red Hat.  I also called Red Hat and they don't recommend Satellite for such a small environment.

Answer (score 1):

Webmin might be worth a look. Pretty simple to set up and does a TON of administrative tasks. Web accessed GUI. [www.webmin.com](http://www.webmin.com)

It does not allow to automate configuration, though. It just makes configuration of each server a bit more user-friendly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Puppet, Ansible or Chef to automate server configuration and deployment of software, but it will require some learning curve at least.
It can be hard for you.

You can use some web control panels like WebMin, but you will need to control one server at the time, so such a tool will only save you a little time and effort comparing with the console.

Take a look [here](https://serversuit.com/community/blog/view/the-server-management-middleground.html) for short comparison of multiple server management tools, hope that will help.

Answer (score 0):

[Puppet](https://puppet.com/) Open Source free version or Puppet Enterprise paid version.

Comment: Could you please expand upon your answer.  it would help if you said why this is a good solution.